# MISP instance through docker on raspberry pi running Ubuntu 20.04 server

Tags: docker, security, malware

Thanks so much in advance for taking the time to read/provide any advice here.

So, I am trying to get an instance of MISP running through docker. The hardware I have it running on is a raspberry pi 4 running Ubuntu 20.04 (server edition).

I thought I installed all software dependencies, but being new to using docker, perhaps I haven't. I'm using this repository for the docker image: https://github.com/MISP/misp-docker

After running the command `sudo docker-compose up` after copying the .env file to the root directory, I get the error that I am going to post an image of below along with the text of the error for easy copy/pasting

```
ERROR: Service 'web' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c bash INSTALL_NODB.sh -A -u' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

[ERROR MESSAGE SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Gf1e.png)

Once again, thank you all for any and all help! Please let me know if I can provide any more information!

Comment: The installation script tries to detect the CPU architecture and Linux variant and fails. It should support armv71-ubuntu-focal. Can you check that `uname -m` returns 'armv71' on your Raspberry?

Comment: Hey! thank you, running that actually returns "aarch64". Any advice from here would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: It looks like this issue which has a fix, but it hasen't been committed yet: https://github.com/MISP/misp-docker/issues/141. The M1 Mac also returns aarch64. If you're feeling adventurous you can try adding the fix to your repo.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this may be an issue that was closed in May of 2021 https://github.com/MISP/MISP/issues/7375. That Docker image has an `INSTALL_NODB.sh` that was initially committed in March 2021 https://github.com/MISP/misp-docker/commit/1e2f18f2c1211e382bd8df5371b1d3d718dad061. Since it was added before that fix the container may not include the fix for rpi that was added in the main repo. To verify, you can check if the output of `uname -m` is in this support map from the script used by the docker image https://github.com/MISP/misp-docker/blob/master/web/INSTALL_NODB.sh#L3070. If it isn't, then you would need this fix implemented in the docker image.

Answer (score 0):

`aarch64` isn't a supported architecture. There's a pull request on the repository that adds it, so you can add that change to your local repository like this (from a command line in the misp-docker repository):

```
git remote add fukusuket https://github.com/fukusuket/misp-docker.git
git fetch fukusuket
git merge fukusuket/hotfix/build-error-on-m1-mac -m "add aarch64 support"
```

Hopefully the pull request will be accepted soon and then you can go back to using the unaltered MISP git repository.